# Is using an over voltage rated capacitor going to work equivalently in this circuit?

Tags: capacitor, rfid

Total noob at electronics, apologies if this is a daft question.

Circuit picture is here which is a RFID module, but in my case connected to an Arduino Nano rather than a USB dongle.

[image: https://www.electrodragon.com/w/images/c/cf/El125_power_supply.jpg]

I broke the 10 V, 1000 uF capacitor, but happen to have a 25 V, 1000 uF cap. It's across a 5 V supply if that matters. Will it work the same?

The circuit works without a capacitor at all, but the cap somehow increases RFIF tag read distance so I guess its something to do with tuning the antenna resonance?

Comment: That "25 V, 1000 uF" means that the capacitor can handle voltages **up to** 25 V. You're applying 5 V so that's **perfectly fine**.

Comment: No that capacitor has nothing to do with "antenna resonance", if it did, the circuit would not work without the capacitor. This is a **supply decoupling** capacitor meaning it stabilises the supply voltage. There are probably other capacitors on the module that do this as well **but not well enough** and that's why there needs to be an **extra** and **large** capacitor added. Without this 1000 uF cap, there would be a lot of noise on the supply and that decreases sensitivity which lowers the range.

Comment: connecting such a large capacity is against the rules of USB, but I guess that doesn't matter.  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/38361/usb-powered-device-with-multiple-decoupling-capacitors

Comment: In fact, using an over-rated capacitor is almost always a *good* thing. The capacitor will last longer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a large capacitor with low ESR means the Tx will have less loss ( in V+ and V- ) R+ESL impedance paths thus slightly  more output power thus greater range.